# Adding an array of controllers to module in AngularJS : The Best way

Tags: angularjs

I just went through a code where the programmer has created an array of controllers and then added the array to a module.

Following is the type of code :-

```
// the array of controllers
var controllers = {};

//adding a controller to array
controllers.ExampleController1 = function(){};
controllers.ExampleController2 = function(){};

//adding the controllers to module
var ABCmodule=angular.module('ABCmodule',[]);
ABCmodule.controller(controllers);
```

I realized that the controller array is made in global scope. Isnt that dangerous? Moreover is this good style of coding. I prefer only making one variable for module and adding all controllers inside that module. What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

This particlar setup can be solved by:

```
for (var ctrl in controllers) {
    if(controllers.hasOwnProperty(ctrl)) {
        ABCmodule.controller(ctrl);     
    }
}
```

That being said, why not just add controllers directly to module which would be declared first? Also loop can be simplified using lodash's `_.forOwn()`

```
angular
    .module('abc', [])
    .controller('ctrl1', ctrl1)
    .controller('ctrl2', ctrl2); // ...

 function ctrl1() {
 }

 function ctrl2() {
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Angular does this internally all the time, but you don't have to accept its source code style as paragon. It is ok while you keep the variables inside IIFE.

If you want to keep the style in ng vein, you can do like this:

```
ctrlModule.config(function ($controllerProvider, controllers) {
    angular.forEach(controllers, function (constructor, name) {
        $controllerProvider.register(name, constructor);
    });
});

ctrlModule.constant('controllers', { ... });
```